# How do I manipulate votes on a node?

Tags: rating

I have nodes that I want people to be able to vote on. I am currently using the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module for this. My use case also requires me to be able to change vote values on individual nodes if necessary. Please how would I do this?

I do not want to go into the database directly. The end user needs to be able to do this in the Drupal interface. I would also like to be able to restrict to access to this feature to certain roles using the permissions system

Answer (score 0):

## Undo/Cancel in individual vote

Head over to relative path `/admin/structure/rate`, and use the ***edit*** link for the rate widget for which you want to be able to Undo/Cancel a vote.

Next, within `/admin/structure/rate/id/edit` (with `id` corresponding to the widget you selected), scroll down to the section titled "***Interaction***". There you'll be able to change the value for "***Should a second click on the same button delete the vote?***" from "*No*" to "*Yes*". Save your changes, and repeat for each of the rating widgets for which you want to enable this facility.

## Set or delete votes for selected roles

There doesn't seem to be a Drupal interface for this. However, you may want to use the [Services Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_votingapi), which provide [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services/) endpoints (actions) for [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) module. From its project page:

> You are allowed to get votes as flexible as Voting API allows it.
>   You are allowed to set votes as flexible as Voting API allows it.
>   You are allowed to delete votes.

From its [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services_votingapi/tree/README.txt):

> After enabling the module as usual...
>
> 1. Go to admin/people/permissions
> 2. Enable the following permissions for your desired user role(s):
>
>    - Retrieve votes
>    - Set votes
>    - Delete votes
> 3. Go to admin/structure/services
> 4. Click 'edit' next to your endpoint
> 5. Enable the following resources under the 'votingapi' service:
>
>    - select_votes
>    - set_votes
>    - delete_votes

And the issue about [How to use this services resources?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2145873) contains an interesting (JSON) samples about how to actually **set votes***.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. An example would be if I wanted to increase the vote count from say 10 to 200

Comment: @ToyanAdeniji-Adele : So "*an end user needs to be able to do this in he Drupal interface*" (as in your question), i.e. increase the vote count from 10 to 200?

Comment: Yes, like a web administrator or other type of admin